# The word-spacing css overflows rtl paragraph with numbers

Tags: css, right-to-left, paragraph, word-spacing

I want to use `word-spacing` css for my RTL paragraph that contains some numbers, after using this styles:

```
p {
  direction: rtl;
  text-align: justify;
  word-spacing: 2px;
}
```

It will **overflows the text out of box** and it's a bad format to read the paragraph as you see below, and if we **remove** `word-spacing` style, it'll look good! Here is the example:

[CSS RTL-WordSpacing-Numberd Paragraph Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h7Uls.jpg)

https://jsfiddle.net/L4bs855h/2/

I found this problem is with `word-spacing`, `RTL Direction` and `Numbers in Paragraph`, but don't know how to solve this problem, and of course I need these 3 things with together.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried using padding?

Comment: `padding-right: 2px;`

Comment: @HarunDilukaHeshan Problem still remains with padding, you can try in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L4bs855h/2/) that I linked above. The problem is about of start of lines that unordered and looks ugly. You can see that [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h7Uls.jpg) I inserted above.